# WPF DataGrid - Set a cell into edit mode programmatically

Tags: wpf, datagrid

- I have a WPF DataGrid that shows some data records (bounded to an ObservableCollection).
- When the user clicks "Edit" button, the currend selected row should move into edit-mode (As if the user double-clicked this row).

How do I do that?

Comment: [Found another post that answers this question.][1]  Worked for me.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421597/how-to-set-focus-to-particular-cell-of-wpf-toolkit-datagrid

Answer (score 11):

Assuming WPF:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg".... />
```

Then this code will work:

```
dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dg.Items[i], dg.Columns[j]);
dg.BeginEdit();
```

Comment: Note that the order of columns in the `dg.Columns` collection is not necessarily the order displayed on screen, see the note in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns(v=vs.110).aspx#.  If you do need to index by the display order, simply store `dg.Columns.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayIndex).ToArray()` in a local variable, and index into that array instead.

Answer (score 8):

[Here is the documentation of the WPF DataGrid on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(VS.100).aspx). The [BeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189733(VS.100).aspx) method seems to be what you are looking for.

PS: I don't know if this is suitable for your application, but many DataGrid users find [Single-Click Editing](https://web.archive.org/web/20130831031733/http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing&ProjectName=wpf) useful.