# how to set focus to particular cell of WPF toolkit datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using WPF toolkit provided DataGrid control to display product list along with its OpenStock, Description etc. In this DataGrid i have set OpenStock column to editable and rest are non-editable. What i want now when my this windows loads, I want to set keyboard focus to first cell of OpenStock column and if possible in edit mode. I searched this for 2 days and finally posting here.

any help or code sample would be helpful.

```
<my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="2,2,2,55" 
x:Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White"    
AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" 
SelectionUnit="Cell" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="True">
        <my:DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="errorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-2"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </my:DataGrid.Resources>
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Width="60" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False" Binding="{Binding Path=pCode}" Header="Code" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding pName}" Header="Description"  IsReadOnly="True" />
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Binding="{Binding CloseStock}" Header="Closing Stock"  IsReadOnly="True" />
            <my:DataGridTextColumn  Width="100" Binding="{Binding OpenStock, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Header="Open Stock"
                                   EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}"/>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Binding="{Binding YrlyOpenStock}" Header="Yearly Opening"  IsReadOnly="True" />

        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
```

thanks alot........

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to set the current cell to the one you want edited and then call [BeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189733(VS.100).aspx) in your Loaded handler:

```
dataGrid1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(
    dataGrid1.Items[0], dataGrid1.Columns[3]);
dataGrid1.BeginEdit();
```

If you give your DataGridTextColumn a name in XAML you can use that name rather than `Columns[3]`.

Comment: Great answer. I had to set the focus on the dataGrid "dataGrid1.Focus();" first but then it worked.

Comment: Note that the order of columns in the `dataGrid1.Columns` collection is not necessarily the order displayed on screen, see the note in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns(v=vs.110).aspx#.  If you do need to index by the display order, simply store `dataGrid1.Columns.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayIndex).ToArray()` in a local variable, and index into that array instead.

Answer (score 8):

Use this code to move the scroll view to a specific cell:

```
dgv.ScrollIntoView(dgv.Items[row], dgv.Columns[col]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have datagrid with TextBox in DataTemplate of DataGridTemplateColumn.
Also i am using Enter instead of Tab to focus TextBox

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var TabKey = new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyboardDevice, e.InputSource, e.Timestamp, Key.Tab);
        TabKey.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
        InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(TabKey);
    }
}
```

I solve focus problem with combination of this code:

```
dataGrid.Focus();
//In case of more columns
//dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.Items[0], dataGrid.Columns[1]);
dataGrid.BeginEdit();
(Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below function, it will work.

```
private void SetFocusOnGrid(DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items.GetItemAt(index));
    grid.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Single;
    grid.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
    grid.SelectedIndex = index;

    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid1.Items[sampleRowIndex], dataGrid1.Columns[sampleColumnIndex]);
dataGrid1.SelectedCells.Clear();
dataGrid1.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);
```

This will select the cell you want to put the focus on.

A DataGridCellInfo object provides information about a cell and the data item that is associated with the cell. It is used instead of a reference to the actual DataGridCell object when the DataGrid control gets a cell, for example in the CurrentCell or SelectedCells properties. Check [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/11/08/how-to-programmatically-select-and-focus-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid-in-wpf/) for more info.