# How to focus on a specific cell when adding a new row to Datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, datagrid

When using Silverlight/WPF Datagrid and you add a new row to the existing collection, how can I jump into a specific cell's edit mode in order to hint to the user that this field needs to be filled out right away?

Many Thanks,

Comment: does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421597/how-to-set-focus-to-particular-cell-of-wpf-toolkit-datagrid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I was able to make it work in SL 5 RC.

```
dg.ItemsSource.Add(data);
dg.SelectedItem = data;                  //set SelectedItem to the new object
dg.ScrollIntoView(data, dg.Columns[0]);  //scroll row into view, for long lists, setting it to start with the first column
dg.Focus();                              //required in my case because contextmenu click was not setting focus back to datagrid
dg.BeginEdit();                          //this starts the edit, this works because we set SelectedItem above
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In SL 4 I had to add "dg.CurrentColumn = dg.Columns[1];" before setting Focus. Othewise, it worked great and this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 4 it is:

```
dg.SelectedItem = data;
dg.CurrentColumn = dg.Columns[1]; // You have to use this line instead
dg.Focus();
dg.BeginEdit();
```