# EditMode set to EditOnEnter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, checkbox

Hi i have made datagrid in wpf, which have one whole column of checkbox. Now if i want to check or uncheck a checkbox, i have to double click the column to make it checked or unchecked. in Winforms we modify the EditMode, but i am unable to find edit mode here any hints?

Comment: Doesn't your keyboard have any commas or points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you know the website called google? I used it and found the answer to your question it's actually here in SO: [WPF DataGrid - Set a cell into edit mode programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629311/wpf-datagrid-set-a-cell-into-edit-mode-programatically)

hope this helps, Davide.

Comment: Yes sir i saw but was not sure it is what i needed because i had in mind that EditMore property.Thanks it works